# PHP Redirect displayed on <div> instead of redirecting to the specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to PHP. 
I am trying to submit a form for the server to process. If a certain condition is met, user will be redirected to a another page. Otherwise, a message will be shown on the same page where the user clicks submit.

The message can successfully be shown using ajax, however the redirection(header redirect on server side) doesnt work, instead the whole page is being shown in the div of the client page

Client Side:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// bind form using ajaxForm 
$('#NextForm').ajaxForm({ 
    // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
    target: '#NextDiv', 

    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
    success: function() { 
        $('#NextDiv').fadeIn('slow'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Am I blind ? or there is ajax request that I cant see ?

Comment: and where is your **php** code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
header('location:' . $urlToRedirectTo);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the message from the server using json_encode(). Add the following codes in you php file in the server.

```
$msg = "This is message";
$myarray = array( "msg" => $msg);
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

From jquery scripts you can have something like this:

```
$.ajax ({
type: 'GET',
url: 'phpfile.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
$("#NextDiv").text(data['msg']);
$('#NextDiv').fadeIn('slow');<br> }
});
```

Note: 'phpfile.php' is the name of the file in the server which is going to send you a message.

Hope it helps you.